Is the expected $L^2$ norm of a vector larger than the $L^2$ norm of the vector elements' expctation?
Suppose random variables $X_1, X_2$ are independent. It's the following inequality true?
$$
\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}) \ge \sqrt{\mathbb{E}^2(X_1)+\mathbb{E}^2(X_2)}
$$
If true, is there any simple proof for it?

Note that this IS NOT the Jensen's inequality!
($\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X_1^2+X_2^2)} \ge \mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2})$)

Do you have an example of a distribution for which this property holds or is this mere idle speculation? Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent?

@DilipSarwate Thank you for answering. I'm not sure what the distribution is exactly.  It's probably a unimodal distribution, such as Gaussian distribution.

@DilipSarwate The variables are independent.

The second part of the inequality can be simplified then, the two expectations are the same

@Firebug They are not the same. I wrote a program for simulation. The inequality holds at least when the variables satisify Gaussain distribution.

Are you saying that $\mathbb{E}^2(X_1)\neq\mathbb{E}^2(X_2)$?

Pick a distribution (it doesn't matter which one) and calculate both sides of the alleged inequality. If the inequality is satisfied for the distribution you have picked, you have the example that I requested. If the inequality is not satisfied, you have the counterexample that shows the alleged inequality to be false.

So now $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not identically distributed anymore?

@Firebug Sorry, my English is poor. I made a mistake when posting the question. the two variables follow different distributions.

@DilipSarwate I wrote a program for simlulation. At least the Gaussian distribution is OK. But I don't know how to prove it.

@Firebug If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are identically distributed, it's there any simple proof for this question?

This question concerns only the single variable $R^2=X_1^2+X_2^2.$  It doesn't matter whether the $X_i$ have the same distribution or even if they are not independent.  Read about Jensen's Inequality.

@whuber How to prove it with Jensen's Inequlity?

All you have to show is that the square root function is concave.  You can do that in many ways, such as by showing it is differentiable throughout its domain and its second derivative is negative within the interior.

@whuber However, if using Jensen's Inequality, I should turn the $\ge$ to $\le$. It's not what I asked.

@whuber Specifically, by Jensen's Inequality, $\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{R}) \le \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(R)}$. The formula is simlar, but not the same.

@whuber Combining the Jensen's inequality result with my question, I have $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X_1^2+X_2^2)} \ge \mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}) \ge \sqrt{\mathbb{E}^2(X_1)+\mathbb{E}^2(X_2)}$. This cannot solve the problem.

That's right, it's not what you asked, because you got the inequality backwards.  You can't expect us to prove something that isn't true!

@whuber I asked "is this true?". I wrote a program for Gaussian distribution, and the inequality holds.

This is a consequence of the reverse Minkowski's inequality $\|f + g\|_p \geq \|f\|_p + \|g\|_p$ for $0 < p < 1$ and $f \geq 0, g \geq 0$.
Applying $f = |X_1|^2, g = |X_2|^2$, and $p = 1/2$ to this inequality yields a slightly sharper inequality
\begin{align*}
E\left(\sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2}\right) \geq \sqrt{E^2(|X_1|) + E^2(|X_2|)}.
\end{align*}

Technical notes

The proof sketch in the above Wikipedia link can be elaborated as follows. Basically the standard Hölder's inequality $\|fg\| \leq \|f\|_p\|g\|_q$ for $p^{-1} + q^{-1} = 1, p \geq 1, q \geq 1$ needs to be reversed when $0 < p < 1$ (hence $q < 0$ so that $p^{-1} + q^{-1} = 1$ still holds), which makes the Minkowski's inequality reversed ( as the key step in the proof of the the Minkowski's inequality calls for the Hölder's inequality). To illustrate this with $p = \frac{1}{2}$ (so $q = -1$), which is the case of your original question, note that the reverse Hölder's inequality is (of course, the reverse versions of these inequalities need additional non-negative assumption of integrands/random variables $X$ and $Y$)
\begin{align*}
E[XY] \geq E^2[\sqrt{X}]E^{-1}[Y^{-1}],
\end{align*}
which can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
E^2[\sqrt{X}] \leq E[XY]E[Y^{-1}].
\end{align*}
But this is then a direct application of the well-known Cauchy-Schwarz inequality after expressing $\sqrt{X}$ as $\sqrt{XY} \times \sqrt{Y^{-1}}$:
\begin{align*}
E^2[\sqrt{X}] = E^2\left[\sqrt{XY} \times \sqrt{Y^{-1}}\right] \leq E[XY]E[Y^{-1}].
\end{align*}

Caveat: although the above inequality holds, the functional
$$X \geq 0 \mapsto \left(\int \sqrt{X} dP\right)^2 = E^2[\sqrt{X}]$$
is no longer a (standard) norm in the space of "square-root integrable" random variables.

As it should be clear now, the independence assumption in the OP is not necessary.



No, this is the classic Jensen's inequality.
According to (this link), $||\mathbf{x}||_2$ is a convex function. Therefore
$$
\mathbb{E}(||\mathbf{x}||_2) \ge ||\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{x})||_2
$$
When $\mathbf{x} = (X_1, X_2)$, the inequality becomes
$$
\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}) \ge \sqrt{\mathbb{E}^2(X_1)+\mathbb{E}^2(X_2)}
$$
This is exactly what you want!

Related: Show that $|\int vd\mu|_2\le\int|v|_2d\mu$..

(updated after seeing the accepted answers).
The question is about a lower bound using only the first moments of $X_1$ and $X_2$. But there is also an upper bound that uses their second moments.
As a consequence of Jensen's inequality, and because the square root is a concave function, we have
$$
\text{E}[\sqrt{Y}] \leqslant \sqrt{\text{E}[Y]}\,,
$$
where $Y$ is a nonnegative random variable. Now substituting $Y=X_1^2+X_2^2$ and using the fact that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent yields
$$
\text{E}[\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}] \leqslant \sqrt{\text{E}[X_1^2]+\text{E}[X_2^2]}\,.
$$

I think this proof is wrong. The formula is similar to my question, but not the same.

The second part of the inequality has the expectations squared

Combining the Jensen's inequality result with my question, I have $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X_1^2+X_2^2)} \ge \mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}) \ge \sqrt{\mathbb{E}^2(X_1)+\mathbb{E}^2(X_2)}$. This cannot solve the problem.

+1 This proof is fine.  If it's unclear that the square root $z\to z^{1/2}$ is concave, note that its second derivative is the function $z\to (1/2)(-1/2)z^{-3/2}$ which, for $z\gt 0,$ is clearly negative.  If the only version of Jensen's Inequality you know concerns convex functions, simply work with the negative square root function $z\to -z^{1/2}.$
